# Using Alerts to Show My Name

Tags: javascript, html, alert

I know it's going to be a dumb mistake but I can't figure it out. Thanks in advance.

HTML:

```
<input type="button" onclick="show_alert()" value="Name" />
```

JS:

```
function show_alert(Name) 
{
    var Name= "Brody";
    alert("Hello from" + Name);
}
```

Comment: Tell us which is the problem. For starters, in the JS code, you use `Name` as a parameter, but in the next line you redefine it as a local variable.

Comment: If your code does nothing then the first thing that needs to be evaluated is: where is your javascript code in relation to your HTML button. Have you included it properly?

Comment: @Asok I don't think it's included at all.  I'm an early beginner.  I don't have a clue of how I would Include it.  Because I click it and it doesn't show anything.

Comment: @BrodyMacfarlane I will show a little demo below as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a minimalistic example of including javascript into your html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" onclick="show_alert()" value="Name" />

    <script>
        function show_alert(Name)
        {
            var Name= "Brody";
            alert("Hello from" + Name);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Above I have included the javascript in my HTML file by using the `<script>` tag, notice that I put it just above the end body tag, this allows the page to render before any javascript is executed.

---

You can also include a seperate javascript file (my preference), like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" onclick="show_alert()" value="Name" />

    <script src="js/file_name.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

I would strongly recommend looking up Javascript for beginner tutorials, there are plenty of great blogs or even youtube videos out there.

Also the web browser console will become your best friend as you become familiar with Javascript.

Comment: Not a problem, we've all been there. Best of luck.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume you actually want someone to input their name as well:

```
<input type="text" id="name" />
<input type="button" onclick="show_alert()" value="Show Name" />

function show_alert(){
  var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
  alert("Hello from " + name");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not sending the value to the `show_alert()` function.

`<input type="button" onclick="show_alert(\"Brody\")" value="Name" />`